# Buck converter question

Tags: power-supply, dc, buck, converter

I am trying to design a step-down power supply. I was searching and browsing from Texas Instruments products and found one that might be the best for my use. I want to step down from 24V to 5V, output current of 1A. I looked into the datasheet and found an example schematic. I know how to select the components around the IC, but I don't know what is Vdd applied do PGOOD pin and what voltage it should be. Thanks for help.

[image: Schematic]

[image: Pin Functions]

Comment: Datasheet says that it is an open drain output for "power good" signal. For VDD level applied to this pin, take a look at "ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS" in the datasheet. Should be around 5V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an open drain output. If output is close to nominal voltage, it's 1, otherwise 0. If you have no use for it, just leave it open.